# twilio App to App calling is not working

Tags: python, heroku, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have setup TwiMl on eroku in Python.
When I call user A from user B, user A didn't get call and VOIP also, while user B is got bot message like "thanks for calling".

When I try to `placeCall` to user B from `PostMan`, user B gets call and also got bot message like "thanks for calling".

PostMan URL : https://myapp.herokuapp.com/placeCall

My requirement is when I call user A from application user B will get call and both can able to communicate.

**Requirement**

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
httplib2==0.9
itsdangerous==0.24
six==1.*
twilio
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Here is my Python TwiMl Code.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.jwt.access_token import AccessToken
from twilio.jwt.access_token.grants import VoiceGrant
from twilio.rest import Client
import twilio.twiml

ACCOUNT_SID = 'ACxxxxxxxx'
API_KEY = 'SKxxxxxxxx'
API_KEY_SECRET = 'TSxxxxxxxx'
PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID = 'CRxxxxxxxx'
APP_SID = 'APxxxxxxxx'


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

    req_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    UserName = req_json['username']
    Password = req_json['password']
    return str(UserName)

@app.route('/accessToken')
def token():

    IDENTITY = request.args.get('identity')
    account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
    api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
    push_credential_sid = os.environ.get("PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID", PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID)
    app_sid = os.environ.get("APP_SID", APP_SID)

    grant = VoiceGrant(push_credential_sid=push_credential_sid,outgoing_application_sid=app_sid)

    token = AccessToken(account_sid, api_key, api_key_secret, IDENTITY)
    token.add_grant(grant)

    return str(token)

@app.route('/outgoing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def outgoing():

    req_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    CALLER_ID = req_json['callerid']
    resp = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()
    dial.client(CALLER_ID)
    resp.append(dial)
    #resp.say("Congratulations! You have made your first oubound call! Good bye.")
    #resp.say("Thanks for Calling.",voice='woman',)
    return str(resp)

@app.route('/incoming', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming():
    resp = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()
    #resp.say("Congratulations! You have received your first inbound call! Good bye.")
    #resp.say("Thanks for Calling.",voice='woman',)
    return str(resp)

@app.route('/placeCall', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def placeCall():

    req_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    IDENTITY = req_json['identity']
    CALLER_ID = req_json['callerid']
    account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
    api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
    client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid)
    call = client.calls.create(url=request.url_root + 'incoming', to='client:' + CALLER_ID, from_='client:' + IDENTITY)
    return str(call.sid)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def welcome():
    resp = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()
    resp.say("Welcome")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**Error Logs**

[image]

TwiML setting on twilio dashboard

Request URL : https://myapp.herokuapp.com/outgoing

Please let me know is there anything that I missed to configure or something that I have done wrong.

Tutorial that I followed to configure TwiML is [Here](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure whether you're building an iOS or Android app, but the idea is the same. When you place a call, like in the example here from the [iOS quickstart in Swift](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/blob/master/SwiftVoiceQuickstart/ViewController.swift#L79), using code like this:

```
TwilioVoice.sharedInstance().call(accessToken, params: [:], delegate: self)
```

you should send some parameters with that call, for example the client identity that you are calling. e.g.

```
TwilioVoice.sharedInstance().call(accessToken, params: ["To": "ClientIdentity"], delegate: self)
```

Then, Twilio will call the URL you set in your TwiML application. In the quickstart the url should be `/outgoing` and in the quickstart application you get an example voice message. To make the call to another application you need to return a different response from `/outgoing`. In this case, you need to use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a nested [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) using the `To` parameter passed when making the call.

In Python/Flask this would look like:

```
@app.route('/outgoing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def outgoing():
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    dial = Dial()
    dial.client(request.form['To'])
    response.append(dial)
    return str(resp)
```

I notice that in the comments on the question you changed the TwiML App URL to `/placeCall`. Make sure you change that back to `/outgoing`.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you please check my updated question and error logs, that would really help me solve my issue

Comment: That's a new error, so it's normally best to open a new question for that. In this case, the issue is that you are importing `VoiceGrant` from the wrong place. You need to `from twilio.jwt.access_token.grants import VoiceGrant`. Check the [access token documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens?code-sample=code-creating-an-access-token-voice&code-language=py&code-sdk-version=6.x) for more detail.

Comment: got another error please check updated question with error logs 
thanks

Comment: This might be because you have installed the latest version of the Python helper library. In this case, try changing all the occurrences of `twilio.twiml.Response` to `twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Can you recreate it and add the new error to your question? And update to show your current code.

Comment: Try updating your import to include `from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse`.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer now! Did the `import` work?

Comment: Ok, what do you have right now and what issues are you seeing? Also, what version of the Python helper library are you using?

Comment: added more details please check 
Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure you pin the Twilio requirement to the latest version, [6.4.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twilio), install and try again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code at the `placeCall` return statement

```
return str(
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial><Client>' + IDENTITY + '</Client></Dial></Response>')
```

Comment: Do i need to change request url on twillio dashboard?

Comment: Ok but i am not sure about placeCall how this will going to call because request url is /outgoing

Comment: sorry change the url at the twilio with the /placeCall

Comment: Ok will let you know